# Variable loss even with global attribute - eval() method - PHP

Tags: php, variables, eval

I am stuck with a variable issue:

I will provide directly some code so that you can understand

```
global $myVar;
setVar('test');
function setVar($value) {
    eval('$myVar = \' '. $value .' \';');
    echo $myVar; //Here myVar is set to $vaue=test
}
echo $myVar; //Here the variable gets back to null, no output at all!
```

why ? I need to find a solution

**EDIT:**

I NEED ABSOLUTELY eval() method due to a for loop which needs to evaluate variables

Comment: move `global $myVar;` inside your function,

Comment: You don't need to use `eval()`, see the PHP documentation of [variable variables](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to declare the variable as a global in the function as well.

```
function setVar($value) {
  global $myVar;
  eval('$myVar = \' '. $value .' \';');
  echo $myVar;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`global` only works inside a function. it does not magically make a variable "superglobal" like you're trying:

```
$myvar = 'foo';
function setVar($value) {
    global $myvar;   // <---global must be used here INSIDE the function
    $myvar = $value;
}
```

There is absolutely no need for `eval()` in your code, and I strongly advise you NEVER to use it. Especially when starting out.

Comment: Thanks but, in this particular case i absolutely need eval() method, and even declaring global inside my function, it still doesn't work. The code here is obviously simplified

Comment: there is NEVER a need for eval(), unless you're trying to write a template system which allows embedding PHP, in which case... DON'T.

Comment: Thanks for your help, and sorry but don't have 176k skill here hehe.. :)